# Using Caret Package but Getting Error in library(e1071)

Tags: r, r-caret

Here is my code:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(32343)
modelFit = train(type~.,data=training, method='glm')
```

It's pretty standard but I am getting the error message:

```
Error in library(e1071) : there is no package called ‘e1071’
```

What's the cause, and how can the problem be resolved?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You need to install the package `e1071`, as the error message is telling you.

```
install.packages('e1071', dependencies=TRUE)
```

Comment: I tried `e1071` but it didn't work. But yours worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

If you will be using the caret package regularly try:

```
install.packages('caret', dependencies = TRUE)
```

This will automatically download package `e1071` as well as `ellipse` and many other package dependancies that arise in using `caret`

for more information please check out the CRAN package page for `caret`
here [caret package info](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html)

Comment: This indeed works, but it is very slow. Maybe number of dependencies is a lot?